# Heroku keys:add using a different path for my keys

Tags: ssh, heroku, ssh-keys

My SSH keys are associated with my root directory and have none associated with each user. When I try to add my keys to heroku i get this response:

```
skline-mac:~ skline$ heroku keys:add
No ssh public key found in /Users/skline/.ssh/id_[rd]sa.pub.  You may want to specify the full path to the keyfile.
```

This makes sense because my ssh keys are actually located at /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. How can I tell heroku to look for my ssh keys there?

Note, because I have locked my ssh directory on my current user using: $ chmod 700 ~/.ssh and $ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*. I no longer know how to access these directories. Sorry I am new to OSX

Also, when I try to do the same command using sudo, I get:

```
skline-mac:~ skline$ sudo heroku keys:add 
/Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:861:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:255:in `activate'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'
```

Note I also get this errory when I try heroku keys:add /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub I get this error:

```
skline-mac:~ skline$ heroku keys:add /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:861:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:255:in `activate'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
    from /Users/skline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question most simply:

```
heroku keys:add /var/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Regarding "locking" your `/~/.ssh` folder, those permissions still give you (their owner) full access to read and write files to them.

<del>And when you run `sudo heroku keys:add` it throws a fit because of something related to RVM + not the user the gem is installed under, and thus when it tries to load a gem it's not finding it. At least, that's my quick assessment from the output you shared.</del> *See comment below for correction.*

Comment: When I do what you said I still get an error. I updated my question to reflect that error.

Comment: Quit using `sudo` for the above mentioned reason. You shouldn't need to run the `heroku` client from root.

Comment: I am sorry, the same error occurs when I it without sudo as you said

Comment: I just looked at your error message a little closer. It looks like you don't have the heroku gem installed outside of your "rails3tutorial" gemset. Jump out of that folder and run `gem install heroku` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I installed it from my home directory and this didn't seem to help. Is there anything else I need to do besides cd .. to my main directory?

Comment: Check your `$ rvm gemdir` while you're there. Your repo is in `/Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial` but the error is occurring in `/Users/skline/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136`. You can also do `$ rvm use default` to get back to the default, then run your gem install.

Comment: When I do this it says: Using /Users/skline/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 with gemset rails3tutorial

Comment: but it says my default includes the gem set rails3tutorial and it didn't seem to help at all.